# looping over paired data.frame columns to do t.test in R

Tags: r, list, loops, dataframe, lapply

In my data.frame `D` (see blow) there are `8` pairs of columns. For example, `Q1_a` and `Q1_b`, `Q2_a` and `Q2_b` ... `Q8_a` and `Q8_b`.

I was wondering how to perform a `t.test` using each pair as the input in BASE R?

For example, the first `t.test` would be `t.test(Q1_a, Q1_b)`, the second is `t.test(Q2_a, Q2_b)` ... `t.test(Q8_a, Q8_b)`.

```
D <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/izeh/m/master/s.csv")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `split` into a `list` with `split.default` and then loop over the `list` with `lapply`, extract the column with anonymous function call and do the `t.test`

```
out <- lapply(split.default(D, sub("_.*", "", names(D))),
         function(x) t.test(x[[1]], x[[2]]))
```

The `sub` will match the pattern of `_` followed by characters (`.*`) from the column names of 'D' and replace with blank (`""`) so that in the `list`, we get each pairwise columns ('Q1_a', 'Q1_b', ..., 'Q8_a', 'Q8_b')

---

In case, we are using `tidyverse`, an option is to pivot to 'long' format and then apply `summarise_at`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
D %>%
    pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = c(".value", "grp"), 
     names_sep = "_") %>% 
    summarise_at(vars(-grp), ~ list(t.test(.[grp == 'a'], .[grp == 'b'])))
```

Comment: @Reza yes, it is splitting in the same order as  in the dataset

Comment: @Reza if you want to be more solid, then use `x[[grep("a$", names(x))]]` and `x[[grep("b$", names(x))]]`